# Interplatform distributed database in cloud

Tags: database, azure, filestream

How can we achieve interplatform distributed database i.e database resides in one cloud platform (say appharbor/Azure) and file stream storage resides in another location (say AWS/rackspace). This is to make use of optimised processing capacity and the locost storage space seperately.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the native Database Replication modules and implement that. Say you are trying to use MySQL and want to replicate the master which in Azure and the slave node in AWS; you need to configure across the cloud vendors and providers.

I strongly discourage this approach because of the following reasons ( few reasons )

- Database is a component which requires good latency. I can understand your idea of HA but it could be too slow, if you try to synchronous commits etc.
- This involves multiple cloud vendors, so there are different APIs, SLAs, compliance involved.
- The replication data would go via public internet, so people generally wouldn't recommend those kind of approaches. Especially for database.

PS - Alternatives

- There are features like `Multi-AZ` in Amazon RDS to make use of in the case of availaility
- There are `reserved instances` in Amazon if you want to leverage relatively lower pricing
- If HA - High Availability or DR - Disaster Recover; your motive behind, you can perhaps take a daily backups and put it in the other cloud vendor. But also, people generally don't do with additional vendors even for this scenario - they try to solve this by putting in different geography i.e. database running in US and backups in Singapore ( Additional Backup )